# Cppcheck GUI : How to enable Cppcheck MISRA addons via the GUI?

Tags: misra, cppcheck

[As you can see all the addon boxes are grayed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRlp0.png)

[Python as added in Preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9trC2.png)
[As you can see in the installation directory there is no addon directory]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7m0qD.png)

Please suggest a way in which I can use this MISRA addon.

Manually added the python path in the path as shown in the above prompt.

Comment: I haven't used the tool but it would appear that some of these require a "premium" version. https://cppcheck.sourceforge.io/ The original MISRA C 2012 + the first 2 addendums should be available though.

Comment: This forum post seems to be about a similar issue: https://sourceforge.net/p/cppcheck/discussion/general/thread/3cdce00e74/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the latest version from git and copied all the folders into their missing places. Also make sure to avoid spaces in paths or else there will be problems with python and the software working

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35831406)